ORCID, public API - get all works of person - URL format for request
A few minutes later I try to get authentication API key for ORCID public API. I haven't received the authentication key yet, but already try to study with the API.
I try to find format of URL, to get a list of all person's works, but I have no success with it. Maybe someone has more experience with ORCID API?
What for: I try to create drupal module that will be import a list of works on a person page. I already find a module that can do it via drupal views https://www.drupal.org/project/views_remote_data . In drupal website, on profile content page, editor will add ORCID person identifier to field, and after saving, on frontent, via drupal View (view remote data) you will see list of person's publications (imported from ORCID).
But, before development of module for drupal I need data for this module, that I must to get from ORCID public API :) And I need your help with this.
So, I know person's identifier, that I can get from URL of person page:
https://orcid.org/0009-0000-4276-4816 (as you can see, this page also has "Works" section). I think that number 0009-0000-4276-4816 is a person identifier in ORCID URL. And, I think, that in ORCID public API must be some URL for request all person's works. I didn't find such examples in documentation.
I need your help with URL format for ORCID (I think with developer API identifier inside) via which, I can get all works of the person.
In documentation https://info.orcid.org/documentation/api-tutorials/api-tutorial-searching-the-orcid-registry/ I didn't find such examples. So maybe, someone has already solved this issue and has more experience with this?
